# Socket.io inside express routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Is it possible to use socket.io inside an express route?

I want it to look like this:

Server

app.js:

```
app.get('/cool_page/',users.cool_page);
```

users.cool_page:

```
if (5>3){
 socket.emit('first_connection',"true statement");
}
```

Client:

```
socket.on('first_connection',function(data){
 if (data === "true statement"){
  console.log("success");
 }
```

So far it hadn't been working. I tried to envelope the users.cool_page in io.sockets.on("conection",function(socket){code...}), but that didn't work. I also redefined some variables inside the users.cool_page; like

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

but it still doesn't work: without really outputting any error.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Best solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559610/socket-io-emit-on-express-route/37560779#37560779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes you just need to make sure you bind the socket calls to the request using a middleware or request emulator. However the better answer here would be for you to leverage a framework such as [expressio](http://express-io.org/) to implement this in a more robust fashion.

Answer (score 0):

To do something like this you will need to link each socket to an express session using something like [socket.io.connect](https://github.com/camarao/session.socket.io)

By itself, socket.io has no knowledge of express's sessions and vice-versa.