# How to send data to all subscriber using Socket.io in node app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, express

This is post-event Route . when a user Posts an event then that event should be sent to all its follower!
I have maintained the Follower Array for that.

How to that using Socket.io ????

```
 module.exports.postEvent = (req,res) => {
       Events.saveEvent(req.body , (err,saveEvent)=>{
          var response = {
              status : 500,
              message : err
          };
          var id = req.userId;
          if(err){
              res.status(response.status)
                  .json(response.message);
          }else {
              // find the data of user from token and
                user.getuserbyname(id ,(err,user)=>{
                    if(err){
                        res.status(response.status)
                            .json(response.message);
                    }else{

                        // send to all user subscribers via socket.io
                        async.each(user.followers ,(id , callback)=>{

                         what will be the code here???


                        })
                    }
              })
          }
      })
    };
```

Comment: I would suggest providing a bit more code, like where you're implementing your socket library in your back end.  Are you using express?

Comment: yeah, i am using express. here in my ASYNC.each loop I am iterating an array of followers and I want to send a new post to every subscriber or follower, so what do I need to write in that for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Attach the [io instance to your app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37560779/1318694) when you setup the `io` server.

```
app.io = io;
```

It's then available via the request object

```
router.post('/event', function(req, res){
  req.app.io.emit('message', data)
})
```

#### Default Room

Each socket connection has a ["Default Room"](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#default-room) identified by its `Socket#id`.

You can send to that room in you request handler with:

```
req.app.io.to(socket_id).emit('my message', msg)
```

Or via the socket in a socket io handler:

```
socket.broadcast.to(socket_id).emit('my message', msg)
```

#### Rooms

SocketIO also provides a concept of [Rooms](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#rooms). Instead of managing subscription arrays your self, you can make sockets `join` and `leave` a room and then emit to that room.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join(`room:${user}`)
})

io.to(`room:${user}`).emit('my message', msg)
```

Comment: if i create a room ! how do i know that room in frontend ?

Comment: Base it on a piece of data the front end and back end share. or emit a message out on connection with the room name.