# how to emit from a controller function with socket.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, mern

I'm building my first MERN app [a message board] and trying to add a mail notification using socket.io.

So far I have in server.js:

```
const io = socketio(expressServer);
const connectedUsers = {};

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.emit('messageFromServer', { data: 'Welcome to the server' });
  socket.on('messageToServer', (dataFromClient) => {
    connectedUsers[dataFromClient.username] = socket;
  });
});
```

to emit from my controller file, do I need the io object or just the socket, and how can I share it/them with the controller file?

All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by from my controller? Are you trying to link http get/post requests to a web socket?

Comment: yes, for relevant notifications :)

Comment: specifically, I want to send a notification to the user when another user sends them a private message

Comment: I see, that could be done with a lookup table for `username => socket.id`. Create it somewhere in your `io` snippet above when you authenticate the user (or have a user id for the socket). and clean up the entry on a `socket` `close` event.

Comment: sorry that should be the `socket` `disconnect` event

Comment: by lookup table, do you mean an object {} ? That was/is the purpose of 'connectedUsers'. I tried exporting it from the main server file with module.exports and importing it to the controller file where I wanted to use it, but to no avail... it was always null because [I assume...] The import happened before the user connected. That's the issue I'm having. Thanks for replying.

Comment: That export/require issue is probably a circular dependency. You are including the controller from the server, and the server from the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup an external file for your user tracking `connectedUsers.js` to avoid [circular dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10869276/1318694).

```
const connectedUsers = {}

module.exports = { connectedUsers }
```

Server Setup:

```
const { connectedUsers } = require('./connectedUsers')

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('messageToServer', (dataFromClient) => {
    connectedUsers[dataFromClient.username] = socket;
  });
});
```

The next problem is getting the `io` instance to the router/controller. I normally [attach the `io` instance to the app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37560779/1318694) in the server setup for this.

```
app.io = io
```

Then in the router/controller you can access the `io` instance from the `req` object:

```
const { connectedUsers } = require('./connectedUsers')

router.post('/message', function(req,res){
  if ( connectedUsers[req.body.username] && connectedUsers[req.body.username].id) {
     const id = connectedUsers[req.body.username].id
     req.app.io.to(id).emit({ msg: 'blah' })
  }
})
```

The `if` check above is an example of the code that will pop up everywhere you use `connectedUsers`. The simple object often turns into a singleton `class ConnectedUsers {}` instance so common code can be attached rather that littered throughout controllers.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll check it all works and let you know.

Comment: No problems. I can remember banging my head against this one!